# What is the origin and meaning of the term 'Chubby Chubs'?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I have this expression stuck in my head and can't figure out where I've heard it. I think it can be a term of endearment for 'plump babies'. But not sure if it has any other connotations because of the terms 'chubby' and 'chub' being linked to the gay scene.

These are the only references I found about this on the web:

- [Is It Wrong To Call Your Toddler “Chubby Chubs” And “Greedy Guts”?](http://goo.gl/4Eff1)
- [Rootabaga Stories](http://goo.gl/Zerld) [By Carl Sandburg](http://goo.gl/lN4Eb)

Comment: *Chubby-chubs* sounds a lot like [Chupa-chups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chupa_Chups), so I’m pretty sure this is simple reduplication for phonoaesthetic effect.

Comment: @tchrist: If you have that garbage in the US too (we're infested in the UK), I'd say it's a racing cert that OP's (unknown to me) usage is at least partially derived from or otherwise linked to it. And from ["chubby **chops**"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22chubby+chops%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), of course.

Comment: Any American English counterpart for the term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=chubby) has an entry for *chubby* meaning "like or resembling a chub". A chub is a type of fish, notably short, thick and stocky. It cites its appearance as in 1610, following *chub* being applied to people around 1560.

*Chubby-chub* is an alliterative/reduplicative term of endearment for someone who is similarly stocky.

I haven't heard "chubby-chub" very much; *chubby-chops* (meaning "plump-cheeked") appears more often in British English.

Comment: Thank you. Is 'chubby-chops' used only for babies or can it be used for anyone in general? Any American English counterpart for 'chubby-chops'?

Comment: I would advise using *chubby-chops* **only** with people you know **very** well.

Answer (score 1):

### Chubby

The OED has the adjective *chubby*, meaning short and thick like the [river fish called chub](https://www.google.com/search?q=chub%20fish&tbm=isch), from 1611, but notes it is obsolete. Meaning round-faced or plump and well-rounded, they have it from 1722. For combinations, they have *chubby-faced* from 1826 and *chubby-headed* from 1884.

*Chubbed*, meaning big headed like a chub, is from 1674. *Chub-cheeked*,  having chubby cheeks or face, is obsolete and from 1715. Likewise, *chub-faced* is obsolete and from 1602. *Chub-headed* is 1796.

### Chubby chops

Searching Google Books, I found *Chubby-chops* in the 1769  *[The History And Adventures Of An Atom](http://books.google.com/books?id=rgsUAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA23&dq=%22chubby%20chops%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JDNdUcvpEenV4gTv-oCwBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=chubby&f=false)* by Tobias Smollett, as a translation of the Italian name Gozzi:

[image: Porcinas Giudices itsColonnas Mura torios Medicis and Gozzi Endea vours Chuckle heads Black Muzzles Hogs Judges Pillars Masons Leeches and Chubby chops]

> You may remember an Italian minister called *Grossa-testa*, or *Great-head*, though in fact he had scarce any head at all. That nation has, likewise, its *Sforzas, Malatestas, Boccanigras, Porcinas, Guidices*; its *Colonnas, Muratorios, Medices*, and ***Gozzi***; *Endeavours, Chuckle-heads, Black Muzzles, Hogs, Judges, Pillars, Masons, Leeches* and ***Chubby-chops***.

A few pages earlier it uses *Chubby-cheeks* as a translation of the Roman name Malici:

[image: What need I mention the Plauti Panci Valgi Vari Vatice and Scauri the Tuditan 9 the Mafia Ceneftellœ and Leccœ in other words the Splay foots Bandy legs Shamble Jhins Baker knees Club foots Hammer heads Chubby cheeisa Bald heads and Letchers I shall not fay a word of the Buteo or Buzzard that I may not be obliged to explain the meaning of the word Tri orchis from whence it takes its denomination yet all those were great families in Rome]

> What need I mention the *Plauti, Panci, Valgi, Vari, Vatiæ*, and *Scauri*; the *Tuditani*, the ***Malici***, Cenestellœ and *Leccœ*; in other words the *Splay-foots, Bandy legs, Shamble-shins, Baker-knees, Club-foots, Hammer-heads, **Chubby-cheeks**, Bald-heads* and *Letchers* ... yet all those were great families in Rome.

### Chubby chubs

This is a much later variation. The earliest I found via Google Books is [*Rootabaga Stories*](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/27085/27085-h/27085-h.htm) (1922) by American author Carl Sandburg, in "The Wedding Procession of the Rag Doll and the Broom Handle and Who Was in It":

> The Chubby Chubs were next. They were roly poly, round faced smackers and snoozers. They were not fat babies—oh no, oh no—not fat but just chubby and easy to squeeze. They marched on their chubby legs and chubby feet and chubbed their chubbs and looked around and chubbed their chubbs again.

Comment: Chubby isn’t obsolete in the UK, it’s still in use.

Comment: *"The OED has the adjective* chubby, *meaning short and thick like the river fish called chub, from 1611, but notes it is obsolete."* -> not in use. *"Meaning round-faced or plump and well-rounded, they have it from 1722."* -> still in use.

Comment: And wot about Chubby Checker? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chubby_Checker

Comment: Chubby Checker's name is a play on Fats Domino, nothing to do with river fish.

Comment: Chubby, from chubby, like a chub, ie fat, is what the play on words with ‘Fats’ is based on. And ‘Chubby’ having that name, indicates that ‘chubby’ meaning fat or plump, was in use in America in around 1953. @Hugo

Comment: Yes indeed! I think we're both basically in agreement here! Words can have multiple meanings, and the plump one you're talking about is still very much in use. It's the fish one that the OED says is obsolete, and I'm certainly not familiar with that sense.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone who loved you at all ever read you the wonderful story of "The Wedding Procession of the Rag Doll and the Broom Handle and Who Was In It" by Carl Sandburg (1967), you would remember that next to last (after the Musical Soup Eaters and before the Sleepyheads) came the Chubby Chubs, who "marched on their chubby legs and chubby feet, and chubbed their chubs and looked around and chubbed their chubs again."

It *was* a grand procession, don't you think so?

Comment: Is there evidence that this is the origin of the term?